# CPU temperature in i3 statusbar

Tags: cpu, i3, temperature

I have Ubuntu 14.04. I am using the i3 window manager and want to display CPU temperature in the i3-statusbar. Folder `/sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0` does not exists and neither does `/proc/acpi/thermal_zone`.

What should I do? I do not want to use `lm-sensors` or similar.

Comment: @phk why did you substitute CPU with CPI?

Comment: Sorry, was a typo.

Comment: on my xubuntu 16.04 system the file you are looking for is at "/sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/hwmon/hwmon2/temp2_input"

Comment: on my lubuntu 16.04 I found it at `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon1/temp1_input`, it's the only one "temp_input" and `temp1_label` is "CPU Temperature", should be it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this something you're looking for? from i3 man page: https://i3wm.org/i3status/manpage.html#_cpu_temperature

> 5.9. CPU-Temperature
>
> Gets the temperature of the given thermal zone. It is possible to define a max_threshold that will color the temperature red in case the specified thermal zone is getting too hot. Defaults to 75 degrees C. The output format when above max_threshold can be customized with format_above_threshold.
>
> Example order: cpu_temperature 0
>
> Example format: T: %degrees °C
>
> Example max_threshold: 42
>
> Example format_above_threshold: Warning T above threshold: %degrees °C
>
> Example path: /sys/devices/platform/coretemp.0/temp1_input

Comment: Something like this, Yes. But as I said I do not have that folder.

Comment: @Wolfgang are there any reasons you do not want to use `lm-sensors`? the status bar is only for displaying temperature sent from another program, i think something like `lm-sensors` is required since to see the temperature a path is needed.

Comment: Ok. I do not want to  use lm-sensors explicitly. If you showed how to use lm-sensors in order to display temperature in status bar, I would use it.

Comment: This might be what you need http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85468/how-to-get-core-temperature-of-haswell-i7-cores-in-i3status

Comment: @Wolfgang https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kVyk1eUWPyE

Comment: Thank you, it works. I do not even thought if it would work without path to something. It is so simple though I do not understand why it works. How to accept the answer?

Comment: @Wolfgang glad to see it works! there should be a gray check mark that you can click to accept the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png

Comment: BTW, If I try to add threshold like it is showed in your answer it does not work. The error message is: *Error: status_command process exited unexpectedly (exit 1)*.

Comment: More specific, problem with a *format_above_threshold* variable assigning,

Comment: hm hard to tell, maybe a typo somewhere?

Comment: No, It is not. More over, the same error occurred If I add *max_threshold* to *usage* clause.

Comment: i have the same problem? what file should I modify?